# Review closed vote - "unclear what you are asking"

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

By now I use the filter to be more effective in reviewing close votes. So I get questions now that are months old without any activity on them. I am not sure if we really need to review questions like them. May be put them in a different queue call "Do when you are bored to death".

Even though I don't necessary see the point in answering them. There is an even worse subgroup. Questions that have an accepted answer.

Do we really need to close questions as "unclear what you are asking" if someone obviously figured it out already?

Comment: 'May be put them in a different queue call "Do when you are bored to death"' - Nope, that's what MSO is for. ;P

Comment: Related to your last sentence: [Why can answered questions be closed as "not a real question"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146716)

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell Didn't see that question before. That was very helpful

Comment: Sure thing, @PeterSchuetze.

Answer (score 2):

Just because someone made a lucky guess and managed to use their psychic powers to divine what the OP was thinking doesn't make the question clear.

An unclear question is a question much less likely to be found by others with a similar problem, making such questions much less useful for future visitors.

Unclear questions also often have a much lower quality of answers.  It may have been good enough for the OP; but this site will, in many cases, hold content to a higher standard than question authors.

Now, if we do know that the posted answer is correct we have a decent shot at actually fixing such a question.  If one or two people were able to figure out what is being asked, and it just took a considerable effort for them to do it, then the question can potentially be edited into one that *is* clear.  That doesn't mean it shouldn't be closed (although it does mean it probably shouldn't be deleted).  Rather, closing it provides a means to allow it to be improved.  (If you want to take the time to improve it now, rather than closing, then by all means.)

Comment: I see your point, but I have seem many 'bad/unclear' questions that helped me more that the clear question. The issue is, that if you are not clear on what or how to ask a certain question, it is sometimes difficult to recognize your issue in a clear/stellar question, but actually easier to understand the bad question of another confused mind.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the question [Why can answered questions be closed as "not a real question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146716) (thanks for pointing it out to Josh Caswell) I got back in line or in other words, see the point why closing the question anyway. Still frustrating to see a growing backlog (especially if it's so huge). Below two major arguments.

> Keep in mind that questions asked here on Stack Overflow aren't just
>   to help you but also to help the thousands of future visitors who will
>   Google for your same exact problem. The questions, and answers, that
>   are most useful in the long run are those that are more targeted. As
>   others mentioned, in most cases, answers don't make the questions. **The
>   question must stand on its own as something of value.**

another example

> I shouldn't have to read a comment thread in order to get all of the info about your question.